# SQLite: getCount() or DatabaseUtils?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to test if a sqlite database is empty or not.  I've read stackoverflow posts and many recommend using rawQuery and getCount() methods.  Others recommend using DatabaseUtils.longForQuery and DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries.

I am looking for speed since the number of rows in the database is large.   I am looking for quick test to see if the number of rows is zero.  If not, it is because there are 1 or more rows in the database.  Would there be a method that aborts the count after 1 row is identified rather than counting all of the rows?  If not, any thoughts on getCount vs. DatabaseUtils?

Comment: just run both and measure the execution times, they shouldnt differ much though

Comment: thanks, that is great idea for testing.  I am trying to learn though which method is superior by design for determining number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;` runs pretty fast.

`DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()` uses this method. I would go with that.

You could run your own `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` that does the above query. That should be good too.

Comment: Ok so use SELECT COUNT with rawQuery?  Like " Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);"

Comment: Either way should work: use the helper function, or write your own function that does the same thing.

Comment: Ok.  Some other posts recommended using "SELECT * FROM".  What is the difference with that vs. your "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"?

Comment: `select count(*)` will be much faster than `select *` and counting the entries yourself (or using `Cursor.getCount()`). `Count()` is a sql function: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: Is that because select * would be counting all records across database rows and columns, whereas select count(*) would just be on one column?

Comment: That's definitely part of it. But I think there might be more to it. Maybe there's an index on the id column too.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.  Answer accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

queryNumEntries as  [Google Doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)   where Added in API level 11

```
long count=0;
Cursor cursor =  Database.DB.rawQuery("select count(*) from table;",null);
count=cursor.getLong(0);
```

Comment: I can try that.  What does the if statement do with moveToFirst()?

Comment: you can ignore it I used to write it.

Comment: OK.  So are you setting count to zero with "long count=0;"?  or is 0 a variable number that then gets incremented with the count?

Comment: No, 0 it's just initial value .

Comment: Ok so what does getLong(0) do?  Wouldn't that set count to a Long value of zero also, whereas I want it show the counted value?

Comment: getLong(0) to get the first columns in row which is value of count(*)